# searchAndRemove an element of a Linked List in C

Tags: c, pointers, search, linked-list

I am making a procedure in C where look for an element in a linked list, save it in some other element dynamically alocated, free it and then return the "saved" element. But the element which I want to return from my procedure is not correct, and when I comment the `free()` line it works like a charm. I thought if I allocated memory for an element and then assigned it some value, it would remain an individual instance, not still depending on the old value

```
typedef struct Queue {
    char name[2];
    int time;
    int priority;
    struct Queue* next;
}Queue;

Queue *searchAndRemove (Queue *x, char *name)
{
    Queue *buf = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    Queue *it = x;

    while (it->next != NULL) {
        if (it->next->name[0] == name[0] && it->next->name[1] == name[1]) {
            buf = it->next;
    //      Queue *del = it->next;
            it->next = it->next->next;
    //      free(del);
        }
        it = it->next;
    }
    buf->next = NULL;   

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Show the code of the function and the list definoition.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please reread the [About] and [Ask] pages, and note that "why isn't my code working" questions cannot be answered except in vague terms like "because you're doing it wrong" unless you show an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your linked list as

```
1 -> 2 -> NULL
```

where `1` and `2` represent the nodes and the arrows point to the next node in the list.

Suppose that the node that you are searching is the last node in the list. ie, `2`.

At some point `it` points to `1` and the condition `it->next->name[0] == name[0] && it->next->name[1] == name[1]` becomes true.

`buf = it->next;` stores `2` in `buf`.
`it->next = it->next->next;` makes `it->next`'s value `NULL`.

Then the last statement of the `while` loop, `it = it->next;` makes value of `it` `NULL`.

On the next iteration, the test condition `it->next != NULL` evaluates `it->next` when `it` is `NULL`. 
ie, attempt to dereference a `NULL` pointer is made. This invokes undefined behaviour.

This could be your problem.

You could avoid this by `break`ing out the loop once the match is found like

```
if (it->next->name[0] == name[0] && it->next->name[1] == name[1]) {
     buf = it->next;
     it->next = it->next->next;
     break;
}
```

Also you should make sure that `x` is not `NULL` in the beginning of `searchAndRemove()`.

And note that if you uncomment those two lines, you freed the memory being pointed to by `del` as well as `buf` as both point to the same memory location. If you return `buf` after freeing `del`, you are using memory which is not allocated and hence invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to remove the comments and put the break, it's still working unproperly. Even though I should've put the break there.

Comment: Don't remove the comments (ie, leave them as commented lines or remove those 2 lines entirely) and put the `break`. And what was the state of your linked list when you called the function to remove an element? And which element did you try to remove?

Comment: I have more queues and I want to search in one for an element specified by name, remove it, and put the returned element into another queue. I just wanted to not leave memory leaks, when I have the free line it just breaks the element components

Comment: You are leaking anyway: `Queue *buf = malloc(sizeof(Queue));` You should instead initialize the pointer to `NULL` and move the `buf->next = NULL` inside the if block.